# Activities loading slowly in app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have created an app that gives a lot of imformation on various topics and stuff.  My app has a lot of images and all are between 200 and 290KB (jpg).  I have a Sliding drawer with Imagebuttons (around 41 ImageButons).  When selecting the category (For example going from the main menu to the information Activity) with these ImageButtons it takes about 2 seconds to load.  However when selecting a imagebutton it displays the image almost instantly. Is there a way of speeding up the loading process going from the main menu to the information Activity?

Answer (score 1):

> around 41 ImageButons

do you **really** need **41 image buttons**? Cannot it be something smarter (like regular button with the same drawable as background so it looks like image button and is not and does not required 41 images to be opened, decoded and used? Also using PNG instead of JPEG could improve this. But in general, rethink your UI

Comment: The reason why i am using jpg is because i am trying to keep the images for the buttons below 60KB where with png it will be around 129KB which then will make the app larger.

Comment: as you see there's no win-win. In your case either smaller either faster. And I a bit doubt you cannot make less than 60K per button with combined, layered drawables.

Answer (score 0):

You must load your image asynchronously: the interface loads immediately, but the image processing tasks are done in parallel and your images will appear progressively.

Basically, you must use `AsyncTask`. The developer portal provides a great tutorial with a downloadable and usable code sample. 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Thanks Ill will take a look at that. Thank you very much.  Hopefully it will solve the problem.

Comment: If interfaces consists of images then this is not a solution (and that was the reason I not mentioned this). What UI you gonna show if all your UI is based on images?

Answer (score 0):

One question: What is your Sliding Drawer for? How many buttons are visible at once? If you just display a few at once and slide through all others via a "right-to-left" swipe then you really should use a `ViewPager` (introduced in api-level 13 I think and available through the support library for every api-level above 4).

What it does: It just loads the ImageButtons that are visible (much like a `ListView` does), so there would be no need for one layout with 41 ImageButtons. You just design a `Fragment` that gets dynamically the different image buttons. Check the documentation for more information: [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)